# Things to keep in mind while editing Mysql "my.cnf" file

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-testing

Today I tried to boost mysql's(installed in my system Ubuntu 14.04) performance as I have many sites(PHP/Magento) installed in my system which relies on mysql as database server, but when I edited the lines like "query_cache_size", "query_cache_type" and other lines(only lines with numeric values which I increased), but instead of speeding it up, it decreased mysql's performance and also it timed-out when I tried to open multiple different pages in browser tabs.

So I need to know what to keep in mind when I edit the "my.cnf" the next time so it doesn't decrease performance but boost it.

What is the relation between those values like "query_cache_size", "max_connections" etc.? Are they inter-dependent ?

Comment: Hmm... tricky without a lot more information. InnoDB or MyISAM. RAM, CPU and HDD config. OS? 32 or 64 bit? Activity GB/day read/write? To answer one of your questions, yes, they are independent. You say that you've changed something and the situation has disimproved - first thing to do is to bring back the _status quo ante_ - i.e. restore your old my.cnf.

Comment: RAM - 8GB, Engine - InnoDB, CPU - Core I3, 32bit system, Activity ? No idea exactly, but as far as I know there are 20(or more) sites installed in my system and I have only one mysql server which is used by all those sites and those sites are frequently accessed about 8 hours daily.

Comment: Also restored to the old default "my.cnf", but still need some suggestions(best with examples) as to how to increase the performance when I have that much sites installed relying on single mysql server.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Linux? It has PAE (Physical Address Extension) - have you set that up? Why not use a 64 bit OS? Post your my.cnf here -  some will have ideas. Anything special about your HDD config - RAID, SAN...?

Comment: I assume you know that query_cache_size is a very special cache, it stores the results of queries based on the exact same SQL text
This is not the general "page" cache for innodb (innodb_buffer_pool_size)
Possibly by increasing many memory areas you used more RAM than you have ? (check "vmstat 1" swap in and out ) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of inter-dependencies.  Casual use of the Query cache can speed up some queries.  Busy systems tend to be slowed down by the QC.

Overcommitting RAM is deadly for performance.  [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory) is a discussion of that, and some of the settings.

32bit system with 8GB of RAM ! -- Is that a 32-bit OS?  Or a 32-bit MySQL on a 64-bit OS?  If the former, then 4GB is *totally* idle.  In either case, MySQL is constrained as if it has only 4GB.

What kinds of things slowed down when you changed what settings?  We can probably explain what happened if you give us some details.